# SQL - Inserting a condition in a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by

My issue is that some of the records in the result set are excluded because they are missing a Min_Date or Max_Date or Both. I need these records to be included so that I can show the runner ran in the race even if he did not reach a First, Last or any checkpoint. Any direction is appreciated.

```
SELECT A.Date, A.RunnerName, A.Duplicates, A.TotalWaypointsReached,
B.FirstWaypoint, C.LastWaypoint, C.rDateTime as MostRecent
FROM (
  SELECT RunnerName,
   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), rDatetime, 101) AS Date, 
   Min(case when FirstWaypoint is null OR FirstWaypoint = '' then null else rDateTime end) MIN_DATE,
   Max(case when LastWaypoint is null OR LastWaypoint = '' then null else rDateTime end) MAX_DATE,

   --IF(I'm missing a Max_Date, Min_Date, or both after all records in a group. Add Max(rDateTime) and Min(rDateTime))

   Count(*) AS Duplicates, 
   SUM(TotalWaypoints) as TotalWaypointsReached
 FROM   Race A
 GROUP  BY RunnerName,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), rDateTime, 101) 
 HAVING Count(*) > 1 ) A
LEFT JOIN Race B
  on A.RunnerName = B.RunnerName
  and A.MIN_DATE = B.rDateTime
LEFT JOIN Race C
  on A.RunnerName = C.RunnerName
  and A.MAX_DATE = C.rDatetime
```

*I'm using the select statement via SQL command in Visual Studio 2008.*

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to replace your `INNER JOIN` to Race on your mins and maxes to an `OUTER JOIN`.  That will get you all your rows from your `A` table and any matches from `B` and `C`.

Comment: Sorry, yes,  `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should do the same thing.

Comment: I need to return C.rDateTime if Max_Date found something, or return the Max(rDateTime) of the records in that grouping in the case that Max_Date is null?